# How to save a 4D image series to a single DICOM file using ITKTools?

Tags: registration, dicom, itk, elastix

I have a couple of 3D CT scans that I would to register using a groupwise registration method by Metz et al (2010) implemented in the elastix registration toolbox (http://elastix.bigr.nl/wiki/index.php/Par0012). The tool requires the 4D data (multiple 3D images) to be encapsulated in a single file. I know this can be achieved with the "pxcastconvert" tool of the ITKTools toolbox (because of a "castconvert4d.cxx" in github https://github.com/ITKTools/ITKTools/blob/master/src/castconvert/castconvert4D.cxx) but I can't figure out the right command line arguments. Usage is:

```
<< "pxcastconvert\n"
<< "  -in      inputfilename\n"
<< "  -out     outputfilename\n"
<< "  [-opct]  outputPixelComponentType, default equal to input\n"
<< "  [-z]     compression flag; if provided, the output image is compressed\n"
<< "OR pxcastconvert\n"
<< "  -in      dicomDirectory\n"
<< "  -out     outputfilename\n"
<< "  [-opct]  outputPixelComponentType, default equal to input\n"
<< "  [-s]     seriesUID, default the first UID found\n"
<< "  [-r]     add restrictions to generate a unique seriesUID\n"
<< "           e.g. \"0020|0012\" to add a check for acquisition number.\n"
<< "  [-z]     compression flag; if provided, the output image is compressed\n\n"
```

If possible, could you advice me on how to combine multiple 3D images in a single file DICOM or MHD file using pxcastconvert?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use MeVisLab. With the DicomImport module you can convert from DICOM slices to a 4D volume which you can subsequently open with an ImageLoad module and save in ITK format using an itkImageFileWriter module. There is a free version of MeVisLab which should be sufficient to perform these kind of tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was in need of a quick solution however, and I ended up using the dicomimport functionality of SPM 2012b.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the program you mentioned will work it out? Because it seems have the cast and convert function, not compose.

I don't know if there is any program can do this, but you may have a look at http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/VectorImages/ImageToVectorImageFilter
It's easy to change the 2d scalar input to 3d and also the output vector.